# Vim - How do I use a key mapping command like <C-L>?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I'm almost certain that someone else has also had this question, and this may be a repeat, but I'm not sure what to call a command like `<C-L>` and so I haven't had any luck finding an existing question. If this is a duplicate, please redirect me.

The question arises from a vimrc section that reads like this:

```
" Map <C-L> (redraw screen) to also turn off search highlighting until the
" next search
nnoremap <C-L> :nohl<CR><C-L>
```

So what combination of keys do I press (in which mode) to input a `<C-L>` mapping?

Comment: this belongs in http://superuser.com/  I think

Comment: @anakata Vim questions are [welcome here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim).

Comment: Ok, but is not that weird?, I mean so then is ok to post notepad++ questions about how to use certain feature? Its weird, but ok, it doesn't bother me that much (like to go and ask in meta why is this...) so is fine.

Comment: @anakata that means, next time you want to ask notepad++ question on SO, add a `vim` tag too. 2 benefits to do so: a) your post stays on SO; b) you could learn why vim is better than notepad++  :)

Comment: @Kent what? It was only an example, who uses vim anyway? I only use ed !

Comment: @anakata you could think my comment above as a joke... and then `Q` or you can `s/vim/ed/g` too.. don't be serious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in this line:

```
nnoremap <C-L> :nohl<CR><C-L>
```

`nnoremap` means `normal no-recursive map <C-L>...` which means, if you press `ctrl + l` in `NORMAL` mode, the mapped key-strokes would be applied.

`<C-L>`  means `ctrl + l`

if you type

```
:h control
```

you can see the keycodes:

```
<C-...>     control-key         *control* *ctrl* *<C-*
```

Comment: This was a great answer for helping me interpret the code, but it says nothing about how to press <c-l>

Comment: @Wadsworth I added that part. at the beginning I thought you got problem with `nnoremap` later I read your question twice, I saw you may want to know the meaning of `<c-l>`

Comment: This updated answer is extremely useful and informative. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The capital "C" character in `<C-L>` represents the control key while the capital "L" character represents a "L" character. So pressing Ctrl+L in normal mode should invoke the mapping.

Comment: are you sure about the `:nn` and visual mode?

Comment: Ctrl+L works like a charm. In 6 minutes, when the system will let me, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Kent's answer ended up being more informative, but this was definitely a great answer. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Wadsworth from the user profile page of Ube, we can see he has been putting effort on vim recently. So I would +1 this answer. because it helped you too.